# How to set up validation in PowerShell that will check status of service and then activate rest of script

Tags: function, powershell

I want to set-up procedure for cleaning tomcat cache folder (when I need it) and I have read about this cmdlets:

```
Stop-Service Tomcat8
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\*"
-Confirm:$false
Start-Service Tomcat8
```

I don't have control over this so I am interested if there is some kind of validation so I can write in console like this:

```
Stop-Service Tomcat8
```

Check if service is stopped.

Write in console "Service is stopped"

```
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\`*"
-Confirm:$false
```

Check if job has been done?

Start service

```
Start-Service Tomcat8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `Stop-Service` will wait for a service to stop by default, but I think it is still possible for it to fail to stop the service and timeout. To add a check you could do this:

```
$TomcatStartup = (Get-Service Tomcat8).StartType

Set-Service Tomcat8 -StartupType Disabled
Stop-Service Tomcat8

If ((Get-Service Tomcat8).Status -eq 'Stopped'){
    Remove-Item "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\*" -Confirm:$false
    Set-Service Tomcat8 -StartupType $TomcatStartup
    Start-Service Tomcat8
} Else {
    Throw 'Tomcat was not stopped'
}
```

I added setting the service to disabled temporarily so that it doesn't get automatically restarted when you didn't want it to.

Comment: Hey Mark I have tested this on my system I get a problem with starting Tomcat8 service. But I will try to configure it further. Thank you for input I now have a starting point.

Comment: I rewrote it a couple of times as I realised I made a couple of mistakes. Did you try the latest version?

Comment: Thanks, this one works I see that you changed .StartType and $TomcatStartup from the last one. :)